# Keras multiclass images classification and prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, classification

I am doing image classification with `ImageDataGenerator`. My data has this structure:

- Train

  - 101
  - 102
  - 103
  - 104
- Test

  - 101
  - 102
  - 103
  - 104

So, if I understood good, the ImageGenerator automatically does what is needed with labeling. 
I train the model, and I get some kind of accuracy. Now I want to do the prediction.

```
- model.predict
- model.predict_proba
- model.predict_classes
```

All these give me the same value. Can you quickly explain or refer(I cannot find anything concerning my problem) how I should proceed, or maybe I did something terrible in the code. The biggest problem, I don't understand how the output will differ for 4 different classes. As `predict_classes` gives me an output `[[1]]`, should not it give me the predicted class?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, MaxPool2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.regularizers import l1, l2, l1_l2

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(60, (3, 3), input_shape=(480, 640,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(60, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(100, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', activity_regularizer=l1(0.001)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='Adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32

# augmentation configuration for train
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=30,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=False,
        vertical_flip=True,
        fill_mode = 'nearest')

# augmentation configuration for testing, only rescale
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# reading pictures and  generating batches of augmented image data

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/media/data/working_dir/categories/readytotest/train',
        target_size=(480, 640),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/media/data/working_dir/categories/readytotest/test',
        target_size=(480, 640),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=800 // batch_size,
        epochs=15,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800 // batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model and the generators not for multi class but binary classification. First you need to fix your model last layer to get output with class size. Second you need to fix the generators to use in multi class.

```py
(...)
model.add(Dense(CLS_SZ))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
(...)

# I am not sure about this read some docs about generator you used.
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/media/data/working_dir/categories/readytotest/train',
        target_size=(480, 640),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/media/data/working_dir/categories/readytotest/test',
        target_size=(480, 640),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode=None)
```

Comment: firstly thanks a lot for your answer. One question, what CLS_SZ means?

Comment: It needs to be your class size.